# Add TODAY and TOMORROW options in datepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I need to add TODAY and TOMORROW options in ngx-bootstrap datepicker. For that I have changed the below code in `bs-current-date-view.component.js` present in `node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-current-date-view.component.js`

```
 BsCurrentDateViewComponent.decorators = [
    { type: Component, args: [{
        selector: 'bs-current-date',
        template: "<div class=\"current-timedate\"><button (click)=\"currentDate()\" class=\"active\">TODAY</button><button class=\"tomorrow\">TOMORROW</button></div>"
    },] },
];
```

But I'm unable to add functionality to that , to take values from today-tomorrow buttons.

Below is the code I have tried till now

```
BsCurrentDateViewComponent.prototype.currentDate = function (en) {
    let today = new Date();
    let dateObj = {};
    dateObj.date = today;
    dateObj.isOtherMonth = false;
    dateObj.isDisabled = false;
    BsDatepickerContainerComponent.prototype.daySelectHandler(dateObj);
    alert();
};

BsDatepickerContainerComponent.prototype.daySelectHandler = function (day) 
{
    console.log(day);
    console.log(this._actions.select(day.date));
    this._store.dispatch(day);
};
```

[image: DatePicker]

Answer (score 0):

I do it in this way

```
const day:{date:Date, label:number, monthIndex:number, weekIndex:number , dayIndex:number} = {date:new Date(), label:label,monthIndex:0, weekIndex:indexes.weekIndex, dayIndex:indexes.dayIndex}

this.datepicker.daySelectHandler(day);
```

**UPDATE**
in your html you have to implement datepicker in this way

```
<bs-datepicker-container #datepicker></bs-datepicker-container>
```

and in your  ts class you should have access to it

```
@ViewChild('datepicker') public datepicker:any;
```

Comment: Tried as you said, still its not working. can you explain a bit more what i need to do

Comment: i was getting `label not defined`, `indexes not defined` error while using your solution.  and also  getting `Cannot read property "daySelectHandler" of undefined` as console error

Comment: @Krishna please look at the UPDATE information I hope it help you